# Can Sharepoint Search Index Version Comments for Versioned Doc Libraries?

Tags: document-library, search, sharepoint-search, version-comments

Perhaps I've been looking in all the wrong places, but I've yet to stumble across a definitive answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint only indexes the latest published revision, the last published version of the document. Previous versions are not indexed out of the box.

Comment: Does this include the comment included in the most recent version?

Comment: It should, the comment is just metadata for the current item. The trick is to look for the Managed Property and if it does not exist, create it and map it to the crawled property. I haven't tried it, but this is always how it's been with SharePoint. If the OOB config does not suit your needs, change it.

Comment: Let me know if you run into issues. If you are new to the process of creating Display Templates I wrote this a while back: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/